# Quartz.Net looking in multiple directories

Tags: quartz.net-2.0

I'm using Quartz.Net 2.X and from what I understand it is scanning the executing directory to look for instances of IJob. Is there a way to define other directories (multiple directories ideally) where to look for "IJobs" ?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways, one of them is to write a custom `ITypeLoadHelper`. In my setup I used the `AppDomain.AssemblyResolve` event to actually have any dependencies load from my custom folder:

```
public class CustomFolderTypeLoadHelper : SimpleTypeLoadHelper
{
    private Dictionary<string, string> dllPaths;
    public override void Initialize()
    {
        string path = @"C:\"; // quick&dirty way
        dllPaths = new DirectoryInfo(path)
            .GetFiles("*.dll")
            .ToDictionary(fi => Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fi.Name), fi => fi.FullName);

        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += (sender, args) =>
            dllPaths.ContainsKey(args.Name) ? Assembly.LoadFrom(dllPaths[args.Name]) : null;

        base.Initialize();
    }
}
```

Then add this line to `quartz.config`:

```
quartz.scheduler.typeLoadHelper.type = MyNamespace.CustomFolderTypeLoadHelper, MyAssembly
```

Or you could use the method `LoadType()` on that interface to do it the Quartz way.

In either case, put the assembly with this bootstrapper class in Quartz bin folder.